# Append an array list to an existing CSV file but it appends and clears the previous data stored in the file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, csv, input

Please could someone help me with this issue, I am trying to get append a new book to a CSV file from user input but it appends to the file and clears the existing data within the file. How do I append the data to the bottom of the file without deleting the original data?

**Code**
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner (System.in);

```
    ArrayList<Books> details = new ArrayList<Books>();
    
    int ISBN;
    String bookType;
    String title;
    String language;
    String genre;
    String releaseDate;
    float price;
    float quantity;
    float addInfo1;
    String addInfo2;
    
    System.out.println("ISBN:");
    ISBN = Integer.parseInt(myScanner.nextLine());
    
    System.out.println("Book Type:");
    bookType = myScanner.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Title:");
    title = myScanner.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Language:");
    language = myScanner.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Genre:");
    genre = myScanner.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Release date:");
    releaseDate = myScanner.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Price:");
    price = Float.parseFloat(myScanner.nextLine());
    
    System.out.println("Quantity:");
    quantity = Float.parseFloat(myScanner.nextLine());
    
    System.out.println("AddInfo1:");
    addInfo1 = Float.parseFloat(myScanner.nextLine());
    
    System.out.println("Addnfo2:");
    addInfo2 = myScanner.nextLine();
    
    details.add(new Books(ISBN, bookType, title, language, genre, releaseDate, price, quantity, addInfo1, addInfo2));
    
    for (Books newBook : details) {
        System.out.println(newBook);

        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        
        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter("Stock.txt", false));

            
            for (Books newBook1 : details) {
                bw.write(newBook1.toString() + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                    if (bw != null) {
                        bw.close();
                    }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Comment: I know there is no validation but I want to get the basic code finished and working before adding stuff such as this :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java check if this works.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to open file for writing in append mode. For the `FileWriter` should be `new FileWriter("Stock.txt", true)`.

The second argument for `FileWriter` should be `true` instead of `false`

Answer (score 0):

the posted code already has the answer, last lines of that part:

> ```
> bw = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter("Stock.txt", false));
> // False here means that we don't want to append data to the content of the file.
> // If we need to append, then we should use true.
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I apologise about the wrongly inserted tag :(

Comment: Approved the edit, thank you for your help